# Login to a website using some code and run a report

Tags: .net

I know this is a strange question, but my purpose is totally legit. I have an login to a website that I get reports every day from. Now I'd like to automate the report exporting just so I don't have to go there and export that csv file 3 times a day.

I've asked them if they had a API that I can use, or if they can schedule an report export to my FTP; but the answer was no to both. So I'd like to know if there is a way I can write some code and login to the website then grab what I wanted every 6 hours...

Let me know if my question doesn't make sense. I just wanted some ideas about this if possible.

Cheers

Comment: you can probably use something like [Curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)

Answer (score 1):

totally possible, in .net you can use the WebClient or the HttpWebRequest to send HTTP Requests like a browser. i cant get anymore specific because i cant say what kind of login the site has (post or htaccess). but you can find examples on how to it very easily

Answer (score 0):

It depends on kind of website and authentication:

1) Using WebClient class

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
wc.DownloadFile(url, "c:\\");
```

2) If the first didn't work, you can achieve it using webbrowser control

```
 HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email");
 if (ele != null)
    ele.InnerText = "username";

 ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass");
 if (ele != null)
    ele.InnerText = "pass";

 ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Login");
 if (ele != null)
    ele.InvokeMember("click");
```

3) Using `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponce`...